# Select distinct duplicated rows from 1:n tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

> I am trying to select customers and their orders in one query, but I get customer and his orders in datatable which customer table columns repeated for each order.
>   I tried `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` but can't do it.

SQL:

```
select * 
from Customer, Order 
where Order.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID 
  and Customer.CustomerID = '2'
```

Tables:

[image: Tables view]

Comment: And the result should be?

Comment: I don't get it. Query is correct. What data you want to avoid?

Comment: Use proper joins. Implicit joins are out of date by more than 20 years.

Comment: The result should be one customer(like customerid=2)row and his orders rows

Comment: This is not the way join works. it can't be done using only joins. you can use 2 different queries in one stored procedure and use them to fill a dataset with 2 tables.

Comment: Fine I'll add it as a comment! It still answers the question.You should be using a `JOIN` rather than the old style matching method you're using here. SQL uses set based operations. The reason why you see repeated information per row/order is because your data set is "normalised". If you want to display this in another fashion, you should do this at application layer, and not within the database.

Comment: Your comment is actually more like an answer @JohnnyBell than an answer you made previously.
We just pointed out that indeed use of `JOIN` is the right way to go but it's not an answer to the question. Answer is: merge same value cells in column in application layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there cannot be different columns for each row you can't do it without having duplicates. Consider reading data separately, once for the customer and once for her orders.

> i want to get all customers and orders the query count will grow.if i
>   have 3 customer i want to get orders and customers in one query.not 6
>   times query execution.

You do not need to perfrom a separate query for each customer. You just need a single query for all customers and a single query for all orders. Then you may connect them in application layer rather than a single query.

But if you argue that you have too many customers and too many orders to hold them all in memory, well, then you may perform a separate query for each customer. That's a tradeoff between memory and CPU.

Comment: I know it possible with separated queries but if i want to get all customers and orders the query count will grow.if i have 3 customer i want to get orders and customers in one query.not 6 times query execution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very rare query, but this my understanding of your need :p.

```
select *
from (
    select 'CustomerID' as col1, 'CustomerName' as col2, 'ContactName' as col3,
        'Address' as col4, 'City' as col5, 'PostalCode' as col6, 'Country' as col7, 0 as ord
    union all
    select CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country, 1 as ord
    from Customers
    union all
    select 'OrderId', 'CustomerID', 'EmployeeID', 'OrderDate', 'ShipperID', Null, Null, 0 as ord
    union all
    select OrderId, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, ShipperID, Null, Null, 2 as ord
    from Orders) res
```

In the result with `ord = 0` you have titles, with `ord = 1` you will have customers only and with `ord = 2` you will have orders, and you can use this query with this condition:

```
where (col1 = @customerId and ord = 1) or (col2 = @customerId and ord = 2)
```

You can add `or ord =0` if you want to add titles in your output.